# Ansible using Windows Modules

Tags: windows, ansible

It's possible move some computer in the Domain Server to especific OU (for example: computers\servers\production) using the Ansible modules ?

Regards,
Stenio

Answer (score 0):

Since Ansible 2.6, there is a module "[win_domain_computer](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.7/modules/win_domain_computer_module.html)", which mitght do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

If you simply want to copy a computer object between ous you'll have to use win_shell or win_command with your own powershell code